# How to fix BibTeX warning about missing author or key fields for webpage-type entries?

Tags: bibtex, warnings

I need to reference some online databases in my LaTeX report. I have them included in my `.bib` file in this format:

```
@misc{StanfordScanRep,
title = {{The Stanford 3D Scanning Repository}},
howpublished = {\url{http://graphics.stanford.edu/data/3Dscanrep/}}
}
```

Compiling the LaTeX document gives **warnings** from **BibTeX** of this form:

```
Warning--to sort, need author or key in StanfordScanRep
```

There is no author for these databases. Is there any other way to fix this warning?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The warning gives you a hint: you can add a `key` field to you entry.

From the BibTeX manual:

> In addition to the fields listed above, each entry type also has an optional `key` field, used in some styles for alphabetizing, for cross referencing, or for forming a `\bibitem` label. You should include a `key` field for any entry whose “author” information is missing;

Accordingly, the given entry can be extended, for example, as

```
@misc{StanfordScanRep,
  key = {Stanford Scanning Repository},
  title = {{The Stanford 3D Scanning Repository}},
  howpublished = {\url{http://graphics.stanford.edu/data/3Dscanrep/}}
}
```

Comment: an example would be nice

Comment: Who is the key values used? Why didn't you fill in the same as in the title field?