# What's the proper way to cite a collective document (specifically, NASA's Design Reference Architecture 5.0)?

Tags: bibtex

I need to cite a NASA document, namely the [Mars Design Reference Architecture 5.0](https://www.nasa.gov/pdf/373665main_NASA-SP-2009-566.pdf). This is a collective document, written with contributions from multiple members. Writing just the name of the editor as the author doesn't seem the correct way but neither does writing every contributor (the document has a page just to list everyone).

I want to know if there is a specific bibtex entry for this kind of documents, or if people just adapt the @article or @book entries to the need. If so, what would these adaptations be?

Comment: Is something stopping you from treating "National Aeronautics and Space Administration" as a *corporate* author, i.e., from writing the `author` field as `author = {{National Aeronautics and Space Administration}}`? [note the use of double curly braces]

Comment: For technical documentation, `biblatex` defines the `manual` entry type.

Comment: @Mico in this case, do I need any reference to the editor?

Comment: `bibtex` has a `key` field that can be used as an alternate to the author(s).  This answer has an example that is similar to your situation: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/88066

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the @inproceedings entry accepts both an author and an editor field, so I just used those.